# Main Differences from Counterparty vs NXT Assets Exchange (SecureAE)

Tags: nxt, decentralized-assets, counterparty

What are the main differences from counterparty and NXT asset exchange? I've been testing out the nxt asset exchange using http://www.secureae.com and using counterwallet. They both seem to be solid products and they both use a separate coin to do their transactions. What other major factors does one need to know before going with one of these decentralized asset exchanges?

Answer (score -1):

Counterparty is based on the Bitcoin blockchain while NXT is not. 
This site compares Colored Coins with Mastercoin with Counterparty, it might be helpful to you: http://www.bitcoin2comparator.org/